# The set of a monic polynomial with $P(0)<0$ is bounded above

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose $p(x)$ is a monic polynomial of degree $>0$ such that $P(0)<0$, which means
$$p(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$$
where $n\ge1,a_0,\cdots,a_{n-1}\in R$, and $a_0<0$.

It asks to prove that $S:=\{x\in R:p(x)<0 \}$ is bounded above.

The professor provided the answer sheet, however, I have a question with the first line.
He set
$$M:=(n-1)max\{-a_0,\cdots,-a_{n-1},1 \} $$
then shows M is an upper bound for S.
Let $x>M$. Than for $k=0, \cdots, n-1$,
$$x^k\ge x>M\ge -(n-1)a_k,$$
$$-\frac{a_k}{x^k}<\frac{1}{n-1},$$
$$\frac{a_k}{x^k}>-\frac{1}{n-1}.$$
Then, we can get
$$p(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0
\\=x^n(1+a_{n-1}x^{-1}+\cdots+a_1x^{-n+1}+a_0x^{-n})
\\>x^n(1+\frac{1}{n-1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n-1}
\\=0$$
Hence, $x\notin S$

I just want to know how the M get setted? I can't see a reason here.

Comment: I do not get the argument after the etc. Please add a few more details regarding your professor's proof, so that we can explain  in more detail whether or not he is correct, and why that is the case.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I just update the missing part, thank you for replying

Comment: Brilliant. Do you want to know "how" such an $M$ was found? Or do you think there is some better $M$ around? I can attempt to give you intuition for why such an $M$ works.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Yes, I would like to know how that M been determined

Comment: @zhw. the question says $p(0)<0$, so I believe it is a set of special x which satisfy the condition

Comment: @BlackTea That was a typo. It should have been "Weird question. All monic polynomials $p$ of degree greater than $0$ satisfy $\lim_{x\to \infty} p(x) = \infty.$ Given that, the result follows (and the condition $p(0)<0$ is not needed)."

Answer (score 0):

In a monic polynomial, the coefficient of the highest power of $x$ is $1$, and therefore positive.

Now, when $x$ is large and positive, which of these is very large : $1,x,x^2,...,x^n$? Naturally, the higher the power of $x$, the bigger the value is. That is, after some time(that is, for very large $x$) , the highest power of $x$ starts taking over the rest of the other numbers. It is like this : when you add $10000$ and $1.5$ and $0.23$ and $0.001$, the smaller numbers don't contribute much to the sum of the four numbers, while of course $10000$ contributes the most. Think of the largest power of $x$ as being like $10000$, and the smaller powers as being like $0.23$,$1.5$ etc.

> In  short, for $x$ large, you can almost stop looking at the smaller terms : it is the largest power of $x$ that dictates what the polynomial does and where it goes.

What is the coefficient of the largest power? It is $1$. So we have $x^n + ...$, where $...$ contains only smaller powers of $x$. If $x$ keeps on increasing, where will this polynomial go? Precisely where $x^n$ goes. Where does that go? Well, it goes to infinity. And that is why, you expect the polynomial to be positive after some time. What time?

Write down the polynomial:
$$
P(x) = x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_0
$$

You want this to be positive. What are the inequalities you get when it is made positive?
$$
x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_0 > 0 \iff x^n > -a_{n-1}x^{n-1} - ... - a_0 \\ \iff 1 > -a_{n-1}x^{-1} - ... - a_0x^{-n}
$$

For $x > 0$. So, all you need, is a number $x$ which is large enough so that the right hand side is smaller than $1$.

One way of achieving this, is as follows: how many terms are on the right hand side? There are $n$ of them, namely $-a_{n-1}x^{-1},...,-a_0x^{-n}$(Your professor has made a mistake. This will be pointed out later on). Suppose we make each of these smaller than $\frac 1n$. Then the sum of $n$ terms, each smaller than $\frac 1n$, will definitely be smaller than $1$.

Pick any term $a_{n-k}x^{-k}$. You want it to be smaller than $\frac 1n$. First of all, make this simplification : since you want just an upper bound, you might as well assume that such a number is greater than $1$, in which case $x^{-1} \geq x^{-k}$ for all $k \geq 1$. Also, if any $a_k$ is positive or zero, then it will reduce the right hand side of the inequality, so we can ignore such $a_k$ in the calculation below, and assume that $a_k$ is positive, so that $-a_k > 0$.

Thus, 
$$
-a_{n-k}x^{-k} \leq -a_{n-k}^{-1} < \frac 1n \iff x > -n a_{n-k}   
$$

So, all we need is that $x $exceed the maximum of these quantities. That is what $M$ is : all you need to do is change the $n-1$ to $n$  above : that was the professor's mistake.